# Получить массив из таблицы БД через PDO

Tags: php, массивы, pdo, sqlite3

Мне нужно получить из БД sqlite массив всех строк таблицы table. Через PDO.

Я перепробовала все, что нашла в сети по этому поводу. Массу примеров.
Но у меня ничего не получается.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно сделать, чтобы сохранить в переменную МАССИВ записей из таблицы table базы данных prop.sqlite3

```
$db_data = new PDO('sqlite:'.__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'prop.sqlite3');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";

$st = $db_data->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$st->execute(array($sql));
```

Большое спасибо!

Comment: Зачем в `execute` передавать `array($sql)`?

Comment: Это была попытка получить результат массивом. Где-то среди тучи мануалов такой пример был. Нужно просто $st->execute() ?

Comment: Ну откройте уже __официальное руководство__ https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php и ознакомьтесь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Уберите из метода `execute()` передачу аргумента, в него должны передаваться параметры, а не сам запрос.
2. После этого добавьте вызов метода `fetchAll()`:

```php
$result = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

[Подробная информация в документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Comment: Я получаю пустой массив в результате. Array                                                                            
(                                                                                
)

Comment: @Наталья, уберите из метода `execute()` передачу аргумента, в него должны передаваться параметры, а не сам запрос.

Comment: Haku Kimura, СПАСИБО! Оформите, пожалуйста свой комментарий ответом, чтобы я могла выбрать его лучшим.  А!!! Это ж Ваш ответ и есть :))